# How to put a break in the output when specific values change using mysqli php

Tags: php, mysqli

I am building a website to list statistics for bowling tournaments over the last 24 years.  Using the following code generates a long, single table showing all the data.  I would like to put a break in the table when the $row['season'] value changes, i.e., from 1990-1991 to 1991-1992, and for each subsequent change of seasons and echo either an html horizontal line between seasons or put the value of the season from the database, i.e., 2013-2014 at the top of each table segment. After a week of searching the web haven't figured out an answer.  Here's the code I have now.  Needs to be mysqli.

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM members INNER JOIN scores ON members.id=scores.memberID WHERE format LIKE '%s%' ORDER BY year, STR_TO_DATE( month, '%b' ), format ASC;");

echo "<table border='0'>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Hometown</th>
<th>Month</th>
<th>Year</th>
<th>Season</th>
<th>Center</th>
<th>Center City</th>
<th>Format</th>
</tr>";

foreach($result as $row) {

  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['firstName'] . " ". $row['lastName'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['hometown'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['month'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['year'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['season'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['center'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['centerCity'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['format'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: Just keep track of the year in your loop. When it changes, create a new row, etc.

Comment: Why don't you; instead of creating this one huge table, create a conditional table to browse by year (i.e. 1991-1992, 1992-1993, etc) ?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is actually already given but it looks like your new with php so here is a smal example i hope its useful to you.
You need to insert some if statements to check if there is any change of year. same goes for any other checks you want to perform.

this is something you could do...

```
<?php
    $lastYear = null;//you can also set the first year manually of course
    foreach($result as $row) {
         //set the first year
         if($lastYear == null){$lastYear = $row['year'];}

         //check if the year changed or not
         if($lastYear == $row['year']){
             //if the year didnt change... do something
         }else{
             //your year changed... do something different
             $lastYear = $row['year']; //update your 'last'year
         }
    }
?>
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: This example if very helpful.  I'm reviewing my database as the first record from some seasons is not showing up in the output.  Want to make sure there is not a problem with the data as it doesn't happen with every year.  Further, I've modified the code to put the season value at the top of each table segment but it doesn't work for the last segment.  Assume this has something to do with the end of records.  Yes, I'm fairly new to PHP but have been around a long time.  Just completed my 50th wedding anniversary.